# unhandled excepcion error de visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Hola tengo un problema el cual no logro resolver y esque visual studio a cada momento muestra un mensaje sin parar de una excepcion que ocurre con el debuger, lo cual no se porque.
Captura del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pregunto es por si alguien le pasa lo mismo o lo ha resulto pueda decirme como solucionarlo. He intentado de todo pero no desaparece.

Comment: ¿Estás ejecutando un programa en particular cuando sucede el error? ¿O simplemente recibes este error a cada vez que lanzas el debugger en Visual Studio, sin importar el programa?

Comment: me lanza este error a cada momento sin abrir nada es decir estoy usando mi sistema operativo windows y me saliendo este error a cada momento lo cual es bastante molesto ya que ni abri visual studio ni nada. reinicie pero sigue apareciendo

Comment: pero es un error de un programa. no de visual studio entonces. Tenes un programa mal instalado

Comment: tienes razon es un programa llamado web companion estaba equivocado disculpar..